# jQuery hide and show input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm looking for is when the box is unchecked don't show any values in the inputs and when the box is checked then show every single input with its respective value.

**This is my code:**

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() { 
    if($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $('.test').val('')
    } else {

    }
});
```

Comment: if you clear the value, how you can show it again?

Comment: Remove `$('.test').val('')` from your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way of doing it is by declaring a variable.

```
var inputValue;
$('#checkbox').change(function(){ 
    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')){
        inputValue = $('.test').val();
        $('.test').val('');
    } else {
        $('.test').val(inputValue);
    }
});
```

For multiple input fields. The idea of @Rashid is awesome. Store the value in the data-value attribute. And when the checkbox is unchecked you can get the values using data-value attribute.

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() { 
    if($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $.each($('.test'),function(){
      $(this).attr('data-value',$(this).val()).val("");
    });

    } else {
$.each($('.test'),function(){
      $(this).val($(this).attr('data-value'));
});
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code is working, but what can I do for multiple inputs?

Comment: By multiple inputs what you mean? Do you want to hide the value of all the input fields when the checkbox is checked or every field will have separate checkbox?

Comment: What I'm looking for is when the box is unchecked don't show any value and when the box is checked show the values on their respective inputs

Comment: For that purpose you will need to give every input field unique id. Then store values in key value pairs in a variable. The id of input field will be key. On unchecking you can then assign the values to each input field by using the key stored in variable.

Comment: Is it the simplest way? There's another?

Comment: I can't say its the simplest way or not. I can just say its one way of doing it. You should try to do it. Think of some other way of doing it. If you find it not working you can always refer back to stackoverflow for help. Happy coding!

Comment: I have updated my answer for multiple input fields as well

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){ 
    var $this = $(this);
  var $item = $this.attr('name');
  var $input = $('input[name="'+$item+'"][type="text"]');
    var $inputValue = $input.val();
  
  if ($this.is(':checked')){
   $input.data('oldvalue',$inputValue);
   $input.val('');
  } else {
   $input.val($input.data('oldvalue'));
  }
 });
});
```

```css
 body{line-height: 1.5;}
 input{display: block;margin: 10px 0 0;}
 input[type="checkbox"] { display: inline;}
 label{ margin: 0 10px 0 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options">
  <input type="checkbox" name="title"><label>Title</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="author"><label>Author</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="category"><label>Category</label>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title:">
   <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Author:">
   <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="Category:">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you remove the value when `#checkbox` is checked. That's not how you hide the element. Just use css display to hide/show the element.

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() { 
    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $('.test').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('.test').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code is only hiding the input and showing it again.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$('#checkbox').change(function() { 
    if($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {

        var value = $('.test').val()
        $('.test').data('value',value).val('')

    } else {

        var value = $('.test').data('value')
        $('.test').val(value)

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onclick="myFunction()">

function myFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `toggle()` jquery function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var item = $(this).attr('name');
        $('input[name="'+item+'"][type="text"]').toggle();
    });
});
```

also check at fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/aaTq3/

Comment: The OP doesn't want to hide the input fields. Instead he wants to empty the values of inputs when checkbox is checked.